# Blender 2.8 Lighting not rendering properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, lighting

[image]

I have an issue with the lighting/rendering in blender 2.8 cycles, in both the viewport and the render modes.

It was working properly a couple of days ago but whilst trying to use it today I can't get lighting to work. I have tried using different lights (spot, point, area and shader emission), played around with the world lighting values but nothing seemed to work.

So I uninstalled blender, re-downloaded and installed a fresh version of blender and built the scene shown in the image and this lighting issue has persisted. It looks as if the direct lighting and shadows are rendered as this ''default/ambient grey'' and the only light that is shown is this weird ''bounce/diffuse'' light.

In the image shown all of Blender's settings have been left at default, the large cube in the back has an emission shader and the other cubes/floor have the default principle shader with only the colour hue changed.

Comment: You have put a very bright mesh light in the scene. How does it look like when you put just a sun lamp in instead? Do you see shadows now? Have you enabled ambient occlusion in the world tab (should be off)?

Comment: I have re-installed my graphic card driver and re-installed blender and re-loaded factory settings, somewhere in this process the problem seems to have been solved. I was leaning towards screwing up my settings somewhere, ambient occlusion might have been on in the world tab.